# What is a .pem file and How to use it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pem

I am designing a new chrome extension and when I package it then I get 2 file: a **.crx** file and a **.pem** file.

I want to distribuite my extension on my server ( shared ) and on Chrome webstore.

Could you tell me what is a pem file and how to use it ?

I can't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**The packager creates two files:**

- a **.crx** file, which is the actual extension that can be installed.
- a **.pem** file, which contains the private key.

**You'll need the .pem later if you want to:**

- Update the extension
- Uploading a previously packaged extension to the Chrome Web Store (make sure that the file is called **key.pem** ([more info](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/3vvygtEajMQ)))

So, do not lose your private key (**.pem**)!

Comment: How to use this private key ?

Comment: @xRobot, added some info about the usage of the .pem file!

Comment: pem make things difficult ... do understand not everyone is cert expert and at the same time not someone is unable to break pem file.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but the "more info" link no longer seems to work. It says either the group is gone or I have no rights to access it.