# What is the Chrome extension .pem file for?

Tags: ssl, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, pem

When I created my first Google Chrome extension, I followed the labyrinth of instructions to a T and was left with a successfully launched extension. I was also left the new owner of an enigmatic .pem file that I was warned to place in a secure spot and never lose. I conscientiously placed the file in a safe place and possibly made several backups while I was at it. It has been several months now, and while I have launched some more extensions and made quite a few updates, I have, not once, looked back at the .pem file. What is this file that I have been guarding with my life -- and would it really be so terrible if I decided to clear out some clutter and delete it?

I have tried to investigate further into what this file is, but for something that is supposedly so crucial, there is very little information out there. The documentation states only:

> **Do not lose the private key!** Keep the .pem file in a secret and secure place; it will be needed to update the extension.

This statement is most definitely untrue, as I have made quite a few updates with nary a glance at the .pem. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733641/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-to-use-it) on SO, but the only information provided is that it is needed to:

> Update the extension

Again, untrue, and:

> Upload a previously packaged extension to the Chrome Web Store (make sure that the file is called key.pem

I am honestly not sure what case that refers to.

I have also managed to glean that the file has something to do with certificates and signing, a topic that I know very little about.

Can someone provide me with a comprehensive explanation of what exactly the .pem is and why, according to everything I've come across, I must keep track of it so carefully?

Comment: @Ty Q. I did upload it to the Chrome webstore. And I've updated it several times since. Not once was the .pem even mentioned. The docs mention it like it's required for any update performed, but it's certainly not required in a normal use case. Do you know of any cases where it is required to support your assertion?

Comment: Like you said it has to do with "certificates and signing", if you want to research more about why it is important for the Chrome Web Store to confirm if you yourself updated the extension you can google the basics of public and private keys in cryptography.

Comment: @TyQ. Then the docs should say it like it is, and not claim that it is required for any update performed. I am unfamiliar with the term "an extension in production"; does that mean one that hasn't actually been properly launched? How can other applications modify an extension?

Comment: @TyQ. What do you mean? At which part of the extension being on the store to the execution of the same extension is it being encrypted?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not very into Chrome development. I tried it out before but I'm no expert. I'm doing a lot of research as I'm trying to answer this question in detail. From where I am starting to figure this out, I believe it's not the extension itself being encrypted but just the details of it so that it cannot be faked. That way Chrome knows that your package is the right extension. I'm trying not to spit out B.S. but at the same time I'm trying to answer the question. I'm going to throw in the towel because I'm getting ahead of myself lol.

Comment: @TyQ. That's fine. But yes, it acts as a casual private key the store uses to validate the user that wants to update the extension. There is at no point **any** encryption done to the extension itself. There is nothing much more here to explain regarding chrome extensions, OP can simply google more about the basics of public and private keys like I said.

Comment: Time since passed aside, thank you for asking a question precisely as it has been on my mind since the launch of my first Chrome extension. You've described my experience with this file to a T. Your exhaustive search and the two current answers will help me to sleep just a little better tonight. Now I can see that in their docs, they refer to a `crx` file which (apparently) is no longer used, so I would imagine the `pem` file was in that same store processing era (likely more to do with apps than extensions anyways). Thanks for the Q. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting#update_url

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the `.pem` (and actually .crx files in general) are no longer used when publishing extensions to the chrome web store. They only come into play for local/sideloading development

The `.pem` file is used in combination with a `.crx` file when you are *NOT* using the chrome store, and instead sideloading your extension.

So, let's say you make an app, package it, and put the file on a fileshare. In the manifest.json, you might have a `update_url` set to deliver updates.

If you want to update the app in this case, it must be signed with the same .pem file when generating the .crx

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate#update_url

Answer (score 4):

The only use I know for the .pem file is to be able to preserve your extension ID when you upload the extension to the Chrome Web Store.

When you first upload an extension, the Web Store generates a new extension ID randomly.
 If you DO NOT want the Web Store to generate an ID but rather you want to keep the ID you had locally on your computer (when you were developing the extension) then you upload the extension with the `key.pem` file included inside the package.

More info here: [How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/)

And here: [Transferring an existing extension to the gallery](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/3vvygtEajMQ)