# A private key for specified extension already exists. Reuse that key or delete it first

Tags: json, google-chrome

Im trying to add a new extension for google chrome.(im new to this).

I keep getting the error message "A Private key for specified extension already exists. Reuse that key or delete it first".

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "test",

   "name": "test",
   "version": "2.1",

   "content_scripts": [
 {
      "matches": ["*://www.google.com*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]

   }



  ]
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In the root folder where your extension is located (or its parent), there is a `.pem` file. Simply delete it.

Comment: I can't find the .pem file either in the extensions folder or its parents. Any advice? Brave is installed in a Sandbox, so the full path starts like this: C:\Sandbox\"Username"\DefaultBox\user\current\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default

Answer (score 4):

I was dealing with that issue too. I changed the root folder name (that contained my manifest and js files) from "extension" to something else like "chromeext" and I was able to pack the extension successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Bumping this thread with a (possible) fix for others : the extension folder name must not contain spaces. *E.g.* change `My Extension Folder` to `MyExtensionFolder`.

Comment: This isn't true in my case (Windows 10). I have a three-word folder name and the extension generated without issue, the .crx and .pem filenames also having spaces.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to Pack Extension it creates a private key with the extension of .pem. Follow this link:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615890/what-is-the-chrome-extension-pem-file-for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQapD.jpg)

This is because you executed extension, it is located in your parent folder. It will appear once you execute it. You need to delete it.
[image]

This can be a one unique key only. So when you execute it again, it will throw again as already a private key exists.